# ImportError: DLL load failed: Не найден указанный модуль. Не увидит cv2

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, машинное-зрение

Программа использует cv2, работаю в conda. Недавно все нормально работало, но потом стала возникать эта ошибка. я недавно начал работать с питоном, пробовал установить заново через `conda install -c menpo opencv` и через встроенные инструменты pycharm, не помогло.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.3.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.3.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/conda/env/прибор 2.7 2/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from function import *
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.3.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\conda\env\прибор 2.7 2\function.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2 as cv
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.3.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ImportError: DLL load failed: Не найден указанный модуль.
```

Answer (score 0):

Помогла ручная установка opencv, пробовал в других средах (pipenv, openenv), там эта проблема отсутствовала. 
https://www.cyberforum.ru/python-graphics/thread2337357.html